# Как вычесть из текущего времени 30 дней?

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать код:

Получить текущее время с помощью `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Из этого времени нужно вычесть 30 дней.Полученное время нужно перевести в LocalDateTime

```
@Component

public class CronTask {
    @Autowired
    private UrlRepository urlRepository;
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?", zone = "Europe/Paris")
    public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println(
                "schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);


    }
```

Comment: И в чём проблема вычислить сколько миллисекунд в 30 днях?

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем ясно, с чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема. Чтобы помочь вам дописать код, необходимо сначала увидеть этот код. Дополните ваш вопрос, нажав на кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: Данный код запускается каждый месяц 15 числа в 10:15:00 по парижскому времени.  Он просто логирует системное время в секундах в UTC.  В чём заключается ваша задача, по-прежнему непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```java
Date monthAgo = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 24 * 3600_000L);
```

Comment: Зачем делать домашку за тех, кто её не пытался сделать? Так ещё и этот вопрос будет висеть на сайте дольше (если этот ответ получит плюсики).

Comment: Это не страшно, вопрос скоро должен быть удалён автоматически.

Comment: Заранее спасибо. Это не домашка, пожалуйста не ругайтесь